# Keyboard input problem Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, input

Did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my Frontier laptop. The desktop booted just fine but sometimes when I open a new window with text input (terminal, browser etc...) I can not type in anything. This happens a lot, for example, if I want to use Terminal then I usually need to open many Terminal windows until I get one that accepts keyboard input.

Been searching for a while with no luck, did anyone know the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand on "cannot type anything". Open a terminal (how do you do this?) and hit Enter. Did you get another prompt? Type ^Q (hold the Ctrl key, type `Q`). Type `pwd` and hit Enter. Anything?

Comment: @waltinator 
**Open a terminal (how do you do this?)** -> Mouse works just fine.

**hit Enter** -> nothing.

**Type ^Q (hold the Ctrl key, type Q)** -> nothing either.

**Type pwd and hit Enter** -> nothing...

One thing in common is, the cursor does react to my typing (it stop blinking when i typed in), but nothing gets printed, no other reaction from Terminal.

Comment: @waltinator after digging more into the problem, it seems that keystrokes outside an input field work just fine. For example I can not type anything into Terminal but if click on Terminal's menu, i can use arrow keys to navigate the menu and character keys to select menu items just fine.